# infinite rediect in views rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancancan

I am new to rails so please excuse any stupidities.
I am building a web application for task management. I am using devise and cancancan gems. What I want is when a user is logged_in, and the user is admin, then all of the tasks should be appear. This is the piece of code in my `application.html.erb` file, which is doing this.

```
   <div class="container">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if can? :index, Task %>
      <% controller.redirect_to tasks_path %>
    <% else %>
      <%= yield %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now whenever a user is logged in. The browser gives error saying `localhost redirected you too many times.` which means its going in an infinite loop. Can anybody please help me what can be the problem?

Comment: Have you considered whether the page being redirected to, is also issuing a redirect (to itself) and why that may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your redirection.

Since you are redirecting from `application.html.erb` to `tasks_path`, It will try to load task's index page with application.html.erb which will again redirect it to `tasks_path` making it as an infinite loop.

Your requirement is not clear from your question but If I understand correctly, you are trying to show all the tasks to the admin and other user can be able to see their own tasks.

For this, you can prepare `@tasks` in the controller itself.

```
def index
  if can? :index, Task
    @tasks = Task.all
  else
    #assuming there is an user_id column for task
    @tasks = Task.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  end
```